# Reference column name from another table to insert value from shared ID

Tags: r, indexing, dplyr, rbind

I am attempting to reference a column in another dataframe (df2) based on a column of column names in my primary dataframe (df1$reference) to return the extact value where the ID and column name match in a new column (df1$new_col). Here is a simplified example of my data and the desired outcome:

[image]

I have tried rbind but ran into errors due to differences in the number of rows/columns. I also tried bind_rows/bind_cols, but am having a hard time joining only the referenced data (I would like to avoid a large join because my real data has many more columns). I feel like indexing would be able to accomplish this but I am not as familiar with indexing outside of simple tasks. I'm open to any and all suggestions / approaches!

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Images are not the right way to share data/code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `row/column` indexing

```
DF1$new_col <- DF2[-1][cbind(seq_len(nrow(DF1)), 
        match(DF1$reference, names(DF2)[-1]))]
```

-output

```
> DF1
  ID value reference new_col
1  1     4      colD      no
2  2     5      colD      no
3  3     6      colE      no
```

#### data

```
DF1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, value = 4:6, reference = c("colD", "colD", 
"colE")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

DF2 <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, colD = c("no", "no", "yes"), colE = c("yes", 
"no", "no"), colF = c("no", "yes", "no")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(DF1, DF2, by="ID") %>% 
  mutate(New_col = case_when(reference=="colD" ~ colD,
                             reference=="colE" ~ colE,
                             reference=="colF" ~ colF)) %>% 
  select(ID, value, reference, New_col)
```

```
  ID value reference New_col
1  1     4      colD      no
2  2     5      colD      no
3  3     6      colE      no
```